# Vuetify not rendering v-menu when built as a webcomponent

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js, web-component

I'm trying to create a Web Component using vue + vuetify.

I know that vuetify doesn't support web components, but I decided to give it a try (for sport) anyway.

Apart from some minor things, like having to manually import CSS, or manually register all vuetify components, everything seems to work fine.

There's however one big obstacle that I hit, which is trying to use `<v-menu>` in a web component. After being built, the button simply does nothing once it's clicked. I only get one warning in the console:

```
console.ts:34 [Vuetify] Unable to locate target [data-app]
```

I already tried making sure `data-app` is present, but to no avail.

I'm building the web component using:

```
npx vue-cli-service build --target wc --name tl-test --inline-vue
```

When I compare the vue project (ran via `yarn serve`) to the web component output (`dist/demo.html`), I can see that when I click the `v-menu` trigger button, the DOM of the dropdown gets created and appended to the page DOM. This doesn't seem to happen with the web component.

What am I missing that would prevent `<v-menu>` from working?

Repository reproducing the issue: https://github.com/samupl/vuetify-webcomponent-issue

Comment: "does nothing once its clicked" Sounds like an Event or ``closest()`` call not escaping shadowDOM

Comment: I actually managed to debug the code and pinpoint the location of the issue. You were close - at some point, vuetify tries to find the "closest app" by doing `document.querySelector("[data-app]")`. A quick workaround was to monkey patch `document.querySelector` for this particular case, but I'm not happy with this solution at all.

If there was an option to build vue as a web component without shadow dom, that would solve the issue (but introduce a new one in the process).

Right now I'm looking for other options.

Comment: can you share the solution please ?. @samu

Comment: Sure. I'm not happy with this solution and I believe in the end we scratched the idea, but it went something like this: https://gist.github.com/samupl/4566a565bca1ac3006387b9044d1193b

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a HTML node to the `attach` prop of [the v-menu](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#links).

This will prevent Vuetify from using a query selector which wouldn't work with shadow DOMs.

For example:

```html
<v-menu :attach="$parent.$el">
...
</v-menu>
```